# pg_array works with Model.new but not with Model.update()

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sequel

I am using Sequel in a Sinatra RESTful API backed by PostgreSQL and have several columns that are integer[] types.

I have registered the `:pg_array` extension and saving new records works fine:

```
x = MyModel.new(params[:mymodel])
x.save
```

However, when I call update:

```
data = JSON.parse(request.body.read)['mymodel']

x = MyModel.where(:id => params[:id])
x.update(data)
```

it fails with the following error:

```
Sequel::DatabaseError - PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: array value must
start with "{" or dimension information
LINE 1: ...olumn2" = NULL, "column3" = 'Some Text', "arrayField" = ('1'), "col...
                                                                    ^
```

The column is defined as `integer :arrayField, :type => "integer[]"` and the JSON representation for the array fields is being passed as `"arrayField":["1"]` in both create and update calls to the API.

It would appear that the array type is correctly picked up for a new record but not when an existing record is updated. Can anyone point out where I've gone wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was calling **Dataset**.update instead of **Model**.update.

The solution was to use .first instead of .where...

```
data  = JSON.parse(request.body.read)['mymodel']

x = MyModel.first(:id => params[:id])
x.update(data)
```

Updating here after getting an answer via https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sequel-talk/w6DBa6mb3rc/UmlYaWD8tXYJ